# Shifting extent of overview map, keeping scale, centering on extent indicator in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, extents, map-series, map-overviews

In ArcGIS Pro 2.7 I've created a map series with a main map frame (1:5000) and an overview map frame (1:250000) with an extent indicator of the main map frame. Once the map series is enabled the extent indicator moves out of my overview map. So the extent indicator should stay in the middle of the overview map frame, the extent of the overview map frame moves. Its like to say "stay focused on the extent indicator, keep scale 1:250 000". If I put the whole map in its full extent in the overview map you wouldn't be able to see the extend indicator of the main map.

Comment: I think what you’re trying to implement in your map series is an index map rather than an overview map.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to make separate Map project files with fixed overview map for each area (like north part , Mid part and south part) this way you can have fixed overview scale for each and still show the extent indicator. You can control the pages of each map series for each file not to repeat. May not be the best way of doing it but I guess it would help.